# Edittext as spinner

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-spinner, layer-list

I have a `editext` which I would like to show as drop down. SO for that I have `background.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item>
    <layer-list>
      <item>
        <shape>
          <solid android:color="#ffffff" />
          <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#000000" />
          <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
        </shape>
      </item>
      <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="right" android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down" />
      </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>

</selector>
```

And added that as background for my edittext. This is what I get:
[image]

As you can see there is slight gap between the image and editext border. I would like to make my edittext like this:
[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: have you tried increasing padding?

Comment: post your edittext widget xml also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/bg"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent" />


        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/bgnew"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_android_black_24dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Create **bg.xml** like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Background Color -->
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

    <!-- Border Color -->
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ff9900" />


</shape>
```

create a **bgnew.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Background Color -->
    <solid android:color="#ffffff" />

    <!-- Border Color -->
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/colorAccent" />


</shape>
```

**Output**

[image: ![image]

Comment: @Arti happy to help you

Answer (score 1):

Create a RelativeLayout with EditText and ImageView UI Components :). 
Don't complicate yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Just try Linear layout with layout orientation horizontal of EditText and ImageView. It is simple.